Node JS API call
I'm trying to export a variable from my function (tradepair) to my index file to use as a variable. The code pulling in the index is this:
const tradepair = require('./modules/binance_api.js'); 
However, every time I run it, I get this error:
`node:internal/process/promises:288
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "false".] {
code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}`
var symbol ="BTCUSDT";
       function tradepair() {
        const apiUrl = 'https://api.binance.us/api/v3/ticker/24hr';
        // Make a GET request
       fetch(apiUrl)
       .then(response => {
         if (!response.ok) {
         throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
       }
       return response.json();
       })
       .then(data => {
           const max = data.reduce((a,b) => a.priceChangePercent > b.priceChangePercent ? a : b ,0);
           console.log("Max Symbol"+" "+ max.symbol)
           console.log("Max Percent"+" "+ max.priceChangePercent)
           symbol = max.symbol;
           console.log("Look at me" + " " + symbol);
           return symbol;
    
   
         })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
     });
     };

     tradepair();


